# Is it possible to have a dynamic linkTo title attribute?

Tags: ember.js

```
{{#linkTo "route" model title=model.title}}model.title{{/linkTo}}
```

This gives the resulting `a` tag a title value of "model.title". I want to iterate a list of models and output a link with a unique title for each.

Can this be done?

Comment: you can do this by writing it as 
{{#linkTo "route" model titleBinding=model.title}}{{model.title}}{{/linkTo}}

Comment: Make that an answer and I'll accept it. Was this answer anywhere in the Ember.js documentation or is this something you know from code only?

Comment: Its the same as we do for view helper also. E.g. for giving plain class names we write:
    {{view App.DummyView class="span4"}}
but for binding we use:
    {{view App.DummyView classBinding="isEnabled:show:hide"}}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on @guleria's comment and for the sake of having this question answered I'll provide an answer.

```
{{#linkTo "route" model titleBinding=model.title}}model.title{{/linkTo}}
```

Providing `Binding` as a suffix to your properties will enable bindings. As for where this is documented, here an extract of the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Binding.html):

> Properties ending in a Binding suffix will be converted to Ember.Binding instances. The value of this property should be a string representing a path to another object or a custom binding instanced created using Binding helpers.

Hope it helps.